# Datagrid.IsSelected Binding and scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, selected

I uses MVVM and I bind datagrid to collection with some code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entites}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}">
```

And I aslo use binding to IsSelectedProperty using style (RowStyle or ItemContainerStyle)

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style>
              <Setter Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelectedProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />                        
        </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

It works well. But if I scroll datagrid down and up, it stops working.

Answer (score 19):

I encountered this problem, and the reason was my DataGrid was using virtualization - when you scroll a selected DataGridRow off the screen, the DataGridRow visual element is either destroyed, and a new one created, or - if the DataGrid's `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` property is set to `Recycling` - it is reused for whatever row is entering the viewport.

When either event occurs, the binding between your ViewModel (with its `IsSelectedProperty` property set) and the DataGridRow (with its `IsSelected` property set) is broken.

To confirm this is the case, try setting the DataGrid's `EnableRowVirtualization` property to false.

In my case, I needed the performance required by using virtualization, and ended up implementing selectability using [Attached Behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx): specifically, a click on a row would use a LeftClickCommand attached behavior to invoke a delegate command on the ViewModel that sets `IsSelectedProperty`. I then used a `DataTrigger` bound to `IsSelectedProperty` in the DataGridRow's style to highlight the row.

This solution essentially involves rolling your own selection mechanism, but it was the only way I found to get both row virtualization and MVVM-friendly row selection.

Comment: Very strange. I'm written about virtualization on the issue, but the text disappeared. Yes, this is the reason. Now I solved the problem through writing code in code-behind.
I need a multi-selection. Is the event triggered when selecting with pressed button "Shift"?

Comment: I added a `Control-Click` behavior so multiple rows can be selected one at a time. Using `Shift` to select a range would be possible, but was not useful enough in my particular instance to justify handling all the corner-case behavior associated with it.

Comment: Can you add an example of your DataTrigger?

Comment: Nice answer.  But isn’t this a bug?  If a listbox item is not on screen and I programmatically set the IsSelected information on the bound VM object to true, scrolling down reveals that the item is selected.  However, if I programmatically set the VM object’s IsSelected to false, scrolling down shows the listbox item as still selected and changes the VM's IsSelected back to true.  Why?  With virtualization, shouldn’t the newly created or recycled listbox item realize it has no idea what the current state of its bound object is and take it’s IsSelected value from the object?  Seems like a bug.

Comment: @DanJ this seems like you have solved this. I agree with FTLPhysicsGuy above, this has got to be a bug. Anyway, is there any chance you can share you solution with me? I am new to WPF and I am really stumped with trying to set the selected items in the Viewmodel from a `DataGrid` with multi-selection enabled!? Any help would be most appreciated...

Answer (score 10):

Try setting the virtualizationmode to standard on the DataGrid: `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"`.

I believe virtualization is turned on by default but the mode is recycling. So the IsSelected property for some reason doesn't get reevaluated when a new row is created on scroll.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! It helped me! After a lot of searching I came here, I really thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're binding in the RowStyle? I've always bound my SelectedItem directly to my SelectedEntity property in my ViewModel.

Comment: Yes. The reason is multiselect.

Comment: Ah. For that I've just created a dependency property called MultiSelect or SelectedItems or something. [link here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/199937/467373.aspx)

Comment: I followed your link and try to implement the example on datagrid. But i I could not get it to update "SelectedItems" property in my viewmodel

Comment: Are you RaisingPropertyChanged on the SelectedItems property? Your code would be helpful. Hard to debug air :)

Comment: I have created simple test project with datagid child [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/k1agt9)