# DataGrid Virtualization interfering with bound item selection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, virtualization

I am using a WPF DataGrid and I have the IsSelected property of the cells bound to data in my model. This works fine if virtualization is turned off on the datagrid (`VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"`).

However, as soon as I turn virtualization on, scrolling down I see that some cells are no longer selected though they were selected in code.

I have to use virtualization because without it my datagrid loading is WAY too slow. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this issue?

UPDATED:

My Code (I bind in code behind b/c I don't know how many columns I need until runtime):

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.CurrentData.Data[0].Length; i++)
    {
        TheGrid.Columns.Add(
            new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = (this.CurrentData.Rank > 1) ? string.Format(this.culture, headerFormatString, i + 1) : string.Empty,
                Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}].DataValue", i)) { ValidatesOnDataErrors = true, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged },
                Width = DataGridLength.Auto,
                ElementStyle = new Style
                {
                    TargetType = typeof(TextBlock),
                    Triggers = { this.errorTrigger }
                },

                EditingElementStyle = new Style
                {
                    TargetType = typeof(TextBox),
                    Triggers = { this.errorTrigger }
                },

                CellStyle = new Style
                {
                    TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell),
                    Setters =
                    {
                        new Setter
                        {
                            Property = DataGridCell.IsSelectedProperty,
                            Value = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}].IsSelected", i)) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged },
                        }
                    },
                }
            });
    }
```

and my IsSelected property:

```
private bool isSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isSelected;
        }

        set
        {
            this.isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code contradicts what you stated before

Comment: Virtualization should not be a problem, as the controls are created and only then the bindings should be evaluated. Can you give concrete steps to reproduce this as well as your binding code?

Comment: oops, copied wrong part of code. @H.B - Maybe it "shouldn't" be a problem...but it is! It works with virtualization turned off and doesn't work with it turned on.

Comment: My guess is that property only gets evaluated on the first pass and is only actually applied to visible cells.  You might try setting VirtualizationMode = standard to get it evaluatued. But my guess is probably worse than my lame answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430132/wpf-datagrid-isselected-binding-and-scrolling

Comment: Looking at your code it seems that the cell level selection has a individual source `IsSelected` property? Do you have different `IsSelected` property for each column? Can you post the code of the class that is `IsSelected` in it?

Comment: @Blam- Good call on the setting mode to standard! That seems to work for me. Add as an answer and I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to fix it when I set the VirtualizationMode to Standard.

Credit goes to @Blam for the suggestion but since he hasn't posted it as an answer yet I am posting. If @Blam posts his as an answer instead of a comment I'll accept as correct, but until then I'm marking this as correct to help future users.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems that the cell level selection has a **shared** source `IsSelected` property and every cell would try to update this property (due to `TwoWay` binding) thereby affecting all the other cells sharing the same source binding.

You would need to revise the code for this.

Can you post the code of the class that is `IsSelected` in it? May be we can change the way this data grid is been setup.

Comment: The IsSelected property is on every value of the bound data so it isn't shared.